# How to reconcile the possibility that Rashi had a slightly different text of the Torah

Tags: rashi, sefer-torah, spelling-variants, mesorah-tradition, parashat-chaye-sara

In the Parshah of Chayei Sara, in [Bereishis 25:6](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0125.htm#6), there is a Posuk that refers to הפילגשים - "the concubines".  Rashi expounds that since the word is missing a Yud, it must be a reference to the fact that Hagar and Keturah were one person and that is how the Torah is alluding to this fact (see Rashi there).

The question is: What missing Yud?

Artscroll's comment answers that: "Rashi's text of the Torah had the spelling פילגשם, without the letter י of the ים suffix which indicates the plural ..."

Does this mean that in Rashi's time the text of the Torah was actually slightly different - so much so that Rashi took the effort to expound a particular missing Yud that we don't actually have on our modern Torah scrolls?

If so, wouldn't it be more appropriate for modern Sofrim to "fix" this issue by leaving out the Yud (since we can trust Rashi on this presumably)?

I'm curious about this.

Comment: This happens a few times

Comment: This isn't an answer, but... is it possible that Rashi, Midrash, even Chazal were just quoting from memory, thus silent letters are present or not according to the author's memory rather than their actual text?

Comment: @yoel, WADR, it doesn't seem reasonable to me that _Rashi_ would "_darshn_" a spelling without being sure first that it was the correct spelling (according to his _m'sora_ or whatever).

Comment: @msh210 Rashi isn't, the Midrash is.

Comment: @avi, all the more so, then.

Comment: @msh210 No, read some of the answers below. The midrash has no reason to care about the actual words in the Torah to make a point. You should read 'bonecha' instead of 'bineicha'

Comment: @msh210 Key point here is that literary thinking in the year 100CE is very different than in the year 1000CE.

Comment: @avi, sure: it may have deliberately disregarded the spelling. But you said (if I understand you correctly) it may have quoted from memory and _erred_ in the spelling it had, i.e. misremembered, and that's what I doubt.

Comment: @msh210 Some of the most insightful puns come from somebody misspeaking, or an error in listening.

Comment: Related: lists of difference in the text of Tanach http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15715/759

Comment: http://leimanlibrary.com/texts_of_publications/88.%20Was%20Rashi's%20Torah%20Scroll%20Flawed.pdf

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rashi is actually quoting here from [Bereshis Rabbah 61](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14385&st=&pgnum=146).

The question is, do we trust the midrash with the text of our *sifrei torah*, and "fix" the problem accordingly, or do we trust the vast majority of our texts and *sifrei torah* that have the word with two *yud's*?

Beis Yosef ([YD 275](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14272&st=&pgnum=450)), who claims that this problem happens quite often, seems to say (correct me if I'm wrong), quoting a *teshuva* of Rashba, that in such cases we follow the majority of accepted texts.

In this case, the accepted consensus seems to be that we write "הפילגשים" with two *yud's*. [See [Minchas Shai](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14036&st=&pgnum=15). This is also discussed by [R' Menachem di Lunzano](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19348&st=&pgnum=20) (see editor's notes on left of following page).]

Comment: Unfortunately (and ironically) it seems the Beit Yosef had a bad Girsa of the Rashba. See [Teshuvat haRashba hameyuchas leRamban 232](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42300&st=&pgnum=152&hilite=).

Answer (score 8):

There is a book called [Fixing God's Torah, Barry Levy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/019514113X). It deals with this Rashba. There is a Rebbi Akiva Aiger in [Masechet Shabbat (55B)](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=233&size=1) where he has a list of such issues. Also note, in the examples given above, they are letters that the gemara ([Kiddushin 30A](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=2686&size=1)) says "we are not expert in full and defective spelling" i.e. the use of the vav. The yud is more problematic but is nonetheless a silent letter. Also see in the back of the final volume of Torat Hayim, Mossad HaRav Kook, there is a short list of variants between torahs.

Comment: MordechaiRockover, welcome to the site and thank you for the information. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site.

Comment: i should also point out that the most interesting thing on shabbat 55b is the tosafot there: "our sha"s argues on our sefarim". מעבירם כתיב. הש״ס שלנו חולק על ספרים שלנו

Answer (score 7):

In [this article](http://www.aishdas.org/toratemet/en_text.html) by Gil Student titled "On the Text of the Torah", this and other textual issues are discussed. In the article (In the Aggadic Midrash section ) he proposes that it was actually pretty common practice for the Rabbis to deliberately "change" the word in order to drive home a homiletic point.

from the article (please read it for context and examples):

> However, we do not need to raise this issue because a more nuanced understanding of aggadic drashot reveals that they are not based on the actual spelling of the words.
>
> ...
>
> Thus, the textual variants we find in aggadic midrashim do not necessarily reflect different versions of the Bible. They reflect the homiletic license that is typical of this literary genre. Some rishonim did not understand it this way.

Comment: To say that Gil is suggesting that the rabbis deliberately "change" the word, is a bit misleading. Particularly given your quote "aggadic midrashim do not necessarily reflect different versions of the Bible."

Answer (score 4):

Rashi's text is not necessarily better than ours. More problematic is the couple of places where its clear that the gemara has a slightly different text than we do. (For example, in Mes. Sukkah the Gemara has a different number of 'vavs' in "sukkos".) Most, if not all, of the rishonim who discuss this issue say the text of the Torah should be changed to match the Gemara's, but no one followed that.

Comment: for example, the Radvaz mentioned in this answer says that when the Rabbis cite a different spelling of the Torah than the one we have, they are more correct, otherwise we follow the tradition we have presently. (It may be that he is not saying we should change the text, but rather we don't negate the teaching just because it is based on a different version of the word than the one we have): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9633/why-are-some-words-in-tanach-read-differently-than-they-are-written

Comment: The article in my answer says: Tosafot in Shabbat 55b said that the Gemara's version of the Bible was different than the textus receptus because the Gemara had מעבירים chaser while the textus receptus has it yeter. However, Rashba (Responsa Attributed to Ramban, 232) wrote that we shouldn't revise our biblical texts based on aggadic midrashim. Similarly, Rashbatz (Tashbetz 3:160)wrote, "We do not rely on aggadic midrashim to correct the texts." Even though we aren't experts in chaser and yeter, we still can't be sure that these midrashim were doing anything more than loosely reading the text.

Comment: @Menachem Worth emphasizing that the Rashba you quote there says not to change for _aggadic_ midrashim, but yes to change for _halachik_ midrashim.

Answer (score 3):

This question was posed to [R. Hershel Schachter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hershel_Schachter) in [this Q&A forum](https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/790227/rabbi-hershel-schachter/q-and-a-tanach-textual-differences-in-the-torah-deciding-halacha-choosing-a-profession/) beginning at about 13:18. He said that there are many such textual discrepancies, and that it is "a big problem" and "a serious problem" and "a serious issue" because it would affect the validity of the Torah scrolls. He quoted the Minchas Chinuch saying that these types of discrepancies don't invalidate Torah scrolls, but did not seem to be entirely convinced. He added that he does not think that this falls under the ambit of Rambam's Eighth Principle that the entire Torah that we have is the Torah that was given to Moshe. (I.e. he thinks that Rambam was not referring to the text.)

Answer (score 1):

According to the commentary in Torat Chaim (seems to be by Rabbi Chaim Dov Chavel [pronounced Schwell]), the word is supposed to be (you would expect it to be) פילגשיים, with *three* yuds. His comment reads:

> כי צריך להיות "הפילגשיים" בשתי יודין, כמו "ועבריים", דהיינו יו"ד אחת לסימן היחס ויו"ד שניה לסימן הריבוי.

So according to this explanation at least, our text is correct (i.e. the same as Rashi's).

Comment: So are you saying our text matches that and has 2 yuds at the end?   it doesn't. It has 1 yud at the end so 2 yuds in total. Not 3. 
 http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0125.htm

Comment: I'm saying Rashi had the same text we do. His comment is that the word "should have" 3 yuds total, but only has 2, so it's "missing" one.

Comment: OK but then should your last line  read "So according to this explanation at least, our text and rashi's text are the same"  rather than "our text is correct". One can't say that according to rashi, ours or his are correct on this word,  if he is saying it should have another yud.

Comment: Edited. Hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: If Rashi is saying it's missing a yud then he's saying it's not correct, he's saying it's incorrect, and on this particular word rather than the whole text or "the text". But, he's not saying it's correct. He's saying it's missing a yud. If one wants to label it as correct or incorrect he's saying that our text on this word is **incorrect**(not correct), in its spelling of the word. The formulation I suggested in my suggested adaption of your last sentence, would be correct and clear "So according to this explanation of rashi, our text and rashi's text have this word the same"