# Where can I find a list of differences between the Aleppo Codex and Ashkenazi texts?

Tags: tanach, mesorah-tradition

Does anyone know of a list of textual differences for all of tanach or at least the chumash between the Aleppo Codex (Keter Aram Soba/Tzova) and the more common text? I already have such a list for Megillas Esther. Nikkud and Ta'amim are not necessary. A link to a plain-text or html version of the more common Torah text would also be useful. Since Mechon Mamre already has the Keter (Breuer) online I could make the comparison myself.

Comment: I've seen a list in the back of a small red book called Keter Yerushalayim but I don't remember who published that edition.

Comment: Odd, because we lost the part of the Keter that includes Megillas Esther...

Comment: @DoubleAA Generally, when people talk about the lost parts of the Keter, they mean Rabbi Breuer's reconstruction published as Keter Yerushalayim.

Comment: @Yitzchak Yes, but precision is never a bad thing around here.

Comment: Be more specific about which codex you're trying to compare the Aleppo codex to.

Comment: To clarify, there is no one 'Ashkenazi text'.  A sofer can copy from any given 'reliable' sefer torah IIRC. Most serious texts will incorporate the Aleppo codex into their editing process.  If you have a specific text to compare to in mind, however, this question may be more answerable.

Comment: @YaakovKuperman I do not know the textual differences offhand, but I have been told that the Aleppo codex has several textual differences that the ashkenazim do not incorporate including a plural in parshas noach where we ashkenazim use a singular and have a rashi to explain the fact. For the sake of making this a little easier let's compare the Keter Yerushalayim Pentateuch to that of the Tikkun Korim Ham'foar.

Comment: FWIW The plural by Noach that you refer to is Gen 9:29. Ashkenazim and Sephardim have it singular ויהי and Temanim and reconstructed-Aleppo have it plural ויהיו.

Comment: Thanks. I look it up every year and forget it some time around Chayei Sarah. (Been a baal kria for a while) According to my local expert sofer there are several pesuchos/stumos too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look in the front of each volume of the common [Daat Mikra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daat_Mikra) series on Tanach (the pink volumes from Mosad HaRav Kook). At the end of their introduction to the book at hand just before the text starts, they bring Rav Breuer's listing of all the textual variants (including trop and nikkud, but not parsha breaks) between the major manuscripts available (including Aleppo, Leningrad, Sason, Cairo, the Venice printing, Minchat Shai and various other Mesorot and collections of Ben Naftali and Ben Asher), as well as which one he chose in writing his version of Tanach which is used in that set.

If you can't find a print copy, the entire set is available online through Otzar HaChochma. Unfortunately it is subscription only, but the first 40 pages of each book are free. So [here is a link](http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?154885&lang=eng) to Daat Mikra on Bamidbar, where the introduction is short enough that you can see the textual variants listed starting on page 31 through the end of the free part.

Comment: just figured i'd ask here: I remember seeing a link to a comparison of the Masoretic and Samartan texts, where can this be found? (I seem to remember you provided the link).

Comment: @mevaqesh http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26980/759

Answer (score 0):

One definite difference between European derived texts and the Aleppo Codex appears in Yeshayahu 9:6.

The latter has the first two words of this verse as לם רבה.
The former, on the other hand, have both these words combined in the Ksiv version - as one word, with the Mem Sofit in the middle of this first word, like this: לםרבה. (The only place in Tanach with such a strange configuration!)

The latter unique word configuration is mentioned in old commentaries, such as the Radak and Even Ezer. In the gemora Sanhedrin 94a, Rashi too makes mention of this unique feature.

Yet the Aleppo Codex is an older version, seen by the Rambam.

It seems that both versions of chumash are very old and that what one set of scholars saw was not seen by the other, thus the commentaries' commentaries.

Comment: I'm not convinced the Aleppo Codex has it as two words there. In any event, just giving one example of a possible difference doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: Double AA: All you had to do to be convinced was look it up at Mechon Mamre. As for not answering the question in full - I made that qualification from the start. A partial answer helps overall. Your comment certainly added nothing.

Comment: Why look at Mechon Mamre when I can just look at the codex itself? Mechon Mamre doesn't always follow the Aleppo Codex. This is not a partial answer. A partial answer would present a location where some of the differences can be found. Listing a single alleged difference with your own history of it is not what is being sought here.

Comment: Isn't there also place with מ at the end of a word?  (I think in Ezra)

Comment: @Heshy Yes (I thought Nechemiah), but that one is definitely not found in old manuscripts IIRC

Comment: @Heshy Nec 2:13 המפרוצים