# Samaritan Torah and its semantic difference with Rabbinical Torah

Tags: rabbis, heterodox, non-rabbinic-judaism

What are the in text semantic differences if any between the [Samaritan Torah and the Rabbinical Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samaritan_Pentateuch#Samaritan_traditions).

Do point out from the text as to how it differs?

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samaritan_Pentateuch#Comparison_with_the_Masoretic

Comment: I am asking intext examples for semantic differences

Comment: Related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1531

Comment: [Here](http://jnul.huji.ac.il/dl/books/djvu/2093934-1/index.djvu?djvuopts) is a book that has all the differences between the Masoratic text and the Samaritan text. (Must have djvu viewer.) Does that help you?

Comment: I HAVE djvu viewer butonly blank pages

Comment: @Ali, Try DoubleAA's link.

Comment: I dont know hebrew much

Comment: @Ali What did you expect from an answer besides Hebrew? Both texts are in Hebrew and you want to know the differences.

Comment: compare the translations?

Comment: @DoubleAA Maybe an English summary of the differences? Or side-by-side translations? Even if such are not available, don't blame the poster for wanting to know the answer to this question despite a lack of Hebrew knowledge!

Comment: @SAH Charles Koppelman gave that answer above. Ali clarified he wanted "intext [sic] examples for [sic] semantic differences". How can I provide in-text examples that aren't in Hebrew?

Comment: Ok, I can't find any English side-by-side comparisons, but I found an [English translation of the Samaritan text](https://sites.google.com/site/interlinearpentateuch/online-samaritan-pentateuch-in-english), and of course you can try to do a comparison using the many English translations of the Masoratic available online (or offline). But I offer my sympathies if you actually attempt such a task, as it would likely be more tedious than any possible reward could justify.

Comment: @jake If you really wanted to do that, don't compare the English directly. Get a list of the Hebrew differences, then look each up in the English. (And note that the majority of the differences are spelling and things like that, so that reduces the list.)

Comment: @isaac What is NARQ here?

Answer (score 6):

You can find a side by side listing of the two texts highlighting all the differences [here](http://dlib.nli.org.il:80/R/-?func=dbin-jump-full&object_id=531240&silo_library=GEN01) from page 17 to 238. (Click on the book image to get started.)

Comment: Ha, I just linked to the same book on JNUL in the comments to the question.

Comment: @jake lol I didn't see. I was finding the start and end pages for the Torah part. I don't think you need a djvu reader to see mine though