# Authenticity of Nach

Tags: tanach, mesorah-tradition, navi-prophets

Is it the general belief that Nach is unchanged since it was written? That the transmission of Nach is as reliable as that of Torah? What types of methods are in place to ensure its accuracy and authenticity? For example, a Torah is disqualified if even a single letter was added/deleted, must be entirely copied from another scroll, the scribe must be trained and learned, and other [checks and balances](http://www.aish.com/h/sh/tat/48969731.html). Does the writing down of Nach require the same?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15715

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Is it the general belief that Nach is unchanged since it was written? "

No.

Nach is not as strictly recorded as the Torah is. The DeadSea scrolls for example show many variants on Nach.  And you will notice in Nach many "corrections" marked in the mikrot gdolot.  The differences between various versions of Nach are not extreme though.  I.e. there is no version that praises something, and another version that condems it.  The average person reading through all the manuscripts of Nach, without a critical eye, likely would not even notice there are differences.

Comment: Many editions of tanach print lists of differences in the back too.

Comment: Just because the Dead Sea scrolls changed the text doesn't mean we did

Comment: @ShmuelBrin And in fact, many of the most noticeable changes in the Dead Sea scrolls (namely מלא spellings like כול, לוא, etc.) are clearly later additions.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Correct. That doesn't change anything about the answer though. The traditional Jewish view is that none of our texts are precisely original.

Comment: @DoubleAA in that case, just source is wrong.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin What source? You are correct that the dead sea scrolls don't prove ours aren't original, but once we know ours aren't (which we do) then there is no a priori reason to assume that ours are more or less original than theirs. If for some reason you wanted to, you could compare the various Qumran texts, the Septuagint, Vulgate and various Masoretic manuscripts to try and guess what the original was, but that's more academia than talmud torah.

Comment: Do you have any source for your assertion? The same logic could be easily applied to the Torah as well.