# which tanach is the most authoritative

Tags: tanach, publications

There are many different Tanachs on the market and while the differences are very minute, they are there. I am under the impression that while it used to be that the Koren Tanach was considered the most accurate, being that they did not use the [Keter](http://www.aleppocodex.org/) it is no longer considered the most accurate. My question is does anyone know the difference between the Tanach's that are based on the Keter

1. The Chorev of R' Mordechai Breur
2. Keter Yerushalayim of Hebrew University
3. Machon Simanim (published by Feldheim
   ?

Comment: Simanim is based on the Keter?

Comment: that is what it says in the hakdama.

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15715/759

Comment: @DoubleAA Doesn't look like the same question afaict.

Comment: @judahsimon I don't see any such claim the hakdama. Moreover, they have ויהי in Gen 9:29 so I highly doubt they are trying to model the Keter.