# Implication of uncertain letters in the Torah

Tags: halacha-theory, midrash, aleph-bet-letters, pentateuch-chumash

I learned that there are a number of uncertain letters in the written Torah

This [article](http://www.torah-code.org/controversy/THE_ACCURACY_OF_OUR_WRITTEN_TORAH.pdf) lists 12 (counts vary).

> (1) Bereishit 4:13 "Mineso" (E&T w/o Vav) (2) Bereishit 7:11
>   "Ma'ayanos (E&T w/o Vav) (3) Bereishit 9:29 "Vayehi" (E&T Vayiheyu (4)
>   Bereishit 46:13 "v'Shimron" (E with Vav) (5) Shemot 14:22 "Chomah" (E
>   w/o Vav) (6) Shemot 25:31 "Te'aseh" (E&T w/o Yud) (7) Shemot 28:26
>   "ha'Efod" (E&T w/o Vav) (8) Bamidbar 1:17 "b'Shemot" (T w/o Vav) (9)
>   Bamidbar 10:10 "Chodsheichem" (T with Yud) (10) Bamidbar 22:5 "Be'or"
>   (T w/o Vav) (11) Bamidbar 33:52 "Bamotam" (E w/o Vav) (12) Devarim
>   23:2 "Daka" (E&T with Alef instead of Heh.

What are the implications of these uncertain letters for halachic derivations from Scripture (where a single letter can be decisive)?

Is there furthermore an explicit listing of laws affected by those letters?

Comment: You think that's bad... See the Gilyon haShas to Shabbat 55b for many more examples.

Comment: highly related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11290/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30704/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44618/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37101/759