# Pesukim in Chumash where Rashi adds in extra words or switches order

Tags: tanach, grammar-dikduk, rashi, pentateuch-chumash

I have been trying to remember examples in chumash where Rashi uses dikduk rules to significantly change the order of words or add words to a passuk so that it has another meaning.

What are some examples of these passukim or the scenarios where this happens?

Comment: does note 14 count? https://books.google.com/books?id=NRvoBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=rashi+quotes+a+word+not+in+the&source=bl&ots=z8wPyFQzvD&sig=ACfU3U3Hb_9Du4ZZiJv0cCxuIyqkKPQrvw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiftPCsn_nlAhVOmeAKHWFqBeIQ6AEwAHoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=rashi%20quotes%20a%20word%20not%20in%20the&f=false

Comment: related? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11290/how-to-reconcile-the-possibility-that-rashi-had-a-slightly-different-text-of-the

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Yael and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!