# Tehillim 72.17 ינין or ינון?

Tags: hebrew, names

Is messiahs name ינין or ינון? I know the vav and the yo'd are very similar, is this why it reads differently ?

Comment: http://www.nathanmerel.com/breadcrumbs-2/50-7/ http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14671/general-understanding-of-kri-and-ktiv

Comment: ינון is a verb not a name

Answer (score 3):

This is a "Kri Ksiv" situation in which it is spelled with a vav and pronounced with a yud Note that it is a verb and it means *will be magnified*

[Tehillime 72:17](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16293#showrashi=true&v=17)

> יְהִי שְׁמוֹ | לְעוֹלָם לִפְנֵי שֶׁמֶשׁ יִנּוֹן (כתיב יִנֹּין) שְׁמוֹ
>   וְיִתְבָּרְכוּ בוֹ כָּל גּוֹיִם יְאַשְּׁרֻהוּ
>
> May his name be forever; before the sun, his name will be magnified,
>   and [people] will bless themselves with him; all nations will praise
>   him.

**Rashi**

> **May his name:** [May] Solomon’s name be remembered forever for his riches and his wisdom.
>
> **before the sun, his name will be magnified:** All the days of the sun, his name will be magnified.
>
> **will be magnified:** Heb. ינון, an expression of kingdom and dominion, as (Prov. 29:21): “he will ultimately be a ruler (מנון) ;
>   (Gen. 21:23),” and to my son (ולניני) , “ who rules over my property
>   after me; (below 74:8),” They said in their heart, their rulers (נינם)
>   together" ; their kings together.
>
> **will bless themselves with him:** A person will say to his son, “May you be wise and rich like Solomon.”

Answer (score 2):

The idea of the name for the Messiah comes first from Tractate *Sanhedrin* which discusses Messiah's appearance. The context of the following comes from Psalm 72:17 -

> [b. *Sanhedrin*, Folio 98B](http://www.come-and-hear.com/sanhedrin/sanhedrin_98.html#98b_28)
>   The School of R. Yannai said: His name is ***Yinnon***, for it is written, His name shall endure for ever:  e'er the sun was, his name is ***Yinnon***.

Another mention of this same verse appears in [*Pesachim*, Folio 54A](http://dtorah.com/otzar/shas_soncino.php?ms=Pesachim&df=54a), which discusses the pre-existence of the name of Messiah.

In other words, the word (or name) of [ינון](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/Lexicon/lexicon.cfm?strongs=H5125&t=NASB) contains not only the meaning of (everlasting) perpetuity, but also of pre-existence.