# Different roots applied to the same verse of 2 Samuel 11:24

Tags: grammar-dikduk, commentaries, language, samuel-shmuel-book-of

[2 Samuel 11:24](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15871#v=24) (Westminster Leningrad Codex) reads:

> [וַיֹּרְאוּ כ] (וַיֹּר֨וּ ק) [הַמֹּורְאִים כ] (הַמֹּורִ֤ים ק)

Two of these come from the root (ק) ירה while the other two come from the root (כ) ירא. How could the verse be translated according to the usage of both roots, and what's the difference in meaning using the one or the other?

Derived from it I also found ירי. Could it be that because "weak" radicals (א, י, ו, ה) can replace one another in cognates, the meaning in this case doesn't change but that it's just unclear from which exact root these words came from?

Comment: consider also asking this on BH.

Comment: Re "How could the verse be translated...", see the answers to question 2 here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14671

Comment: @רבותמחשבות  what's BH. ?

Comment: Biblical Hermeneutics, another SE site, but ask your LOR first. (Monica has a meta post on this somewhere, where has an excellent explanation of why she thinks it should be avoided, but I'm in a phone now.)

Comment: @Levi *on a phone now...  here's the link. https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/429/would-anyone-be-interested-in-helping-out-biblical-hermeneutics/1807#1807